# Spring OAuth2 Refresh token expiration

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, oauth, spring-security-oauth2

I am wondering if my refresh token validity`<property name="refreshTokenValiditySeconds" value="6000" />`
 expires, does spring automatically removes it from DB calling **TokenStore** method `void removeRefreshToken(OAuth2RefreshToken var1);` Or it is handled differently after expiration ?

Answer (score 0):

Spring does **not** expire the refresh token automatically. Your TokenStore implementation has to take care of that. For example a Redis backed token store can expire token key-value pairs autonomously if the key expiry is is set.

`removeRefreshToken(..)` is for explicitly removing stored refresh tokens.

Comment: Can you please help.. How can i bypass this feature of redis using spring